# Trying to get ID from multidimensional array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array, which has been created from getting the pages from user levels. When I use print_r to print out the array you can see that there are arrays nested within arrays.

I am trying to access the 'ID' and 'name' values, which exists in each nested array. I have tried using a foreach and for loop, but have had no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

```
   Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [ID] => 2487 [name] => Student Analytics [_more_] => /levels/1531756603/pages/2487 )
[1] => Array ( [ID] => 1048 [name] => Member Profile [_more_] => /levels/1531756603/pages/1048 )
[2] => Array ( [ID] => 864 [name] => i.4 Course Practicum – Your Live Campaign [_more_] => /levels/1531756603/pages/864 )
[3] => Array ( [ID] => 817 [name] => i.5 Course Expectations – Contact Us If Needed [_more_] => /levels/1531756603/pages/817 )
[4] => Array ( [ID] => 815 [name] => i.3 Course Assessments – Why There Are Level Assessments [_more_] => /levels/1531756603/pages/815 )
[5] => Array ( [ID] => 813 [name] => i.2 Course Structure – How to Navigate the Web Platform [_more_] => /levels/1531756603/pages/813 )
[6] => Array ( [ID] => 807 [name] => Introduction to the Course [_more_] => /levels/1531756603/pages/807 )
[7] => Array ( [ID] => 659 [name] => INTRO LEVEL ASSESSMENT [_more_] => /levels/1531756603/pages/659 )
[8] => Array ( [ID] => 378 [name] => How This Course Will be Taught [_more_] => /levels/1531756603/pages/378 )
[9] => Array ( [ID] => 376 [name] => SCourse [_more_] => /levels/1531756603/pages/376 )
[10] => Array ( [ID] => 372 [name] => Dashboard [_more_] => /levels/1531756603/pages/372 ) )
[1] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [ID] => 2372 [name] => Profile Assignment [_more_] => /levels/1531866216/pages/2372 )
[1] => Array ( [ID] => 2110 [name] => Instructions [_more_] => /levels/1531866216/pages/2110 )
[2] => Array ( [ID] => 1619 [name] => Practicum [_more_] => /levels/1531866216/pages/1619 )
[3] => Array ( [ID] => 1048 [name] => Member Profile [_more_] => /levels/1531866216/pages/1048 )
[4] => Array ( [ID] => 571 [name] => LEVEL 1 [_more_] => /levels/1531866216/pages/571 )
[5] => Array ( [ID] => 506 [name] => 2.A ASSIGNMENTS [_more_] => /levels/1531866216/pages/506 )
[6] => Array ( [ID] => 504 [name] => 2.7 SUMMARY AND REVIEW [_more_] => /levels/1531866216/pages/504 )
[7] => Array ( [ID] => 502 [name] => 2.6 Your Brand is the Balancing Force [_more_] => /levels/1531866216/pages/502 )
[8] => Array ( [ID] => 497 [name] => 2.5 Brand Trust [_more_] => /levels/1531866216/pages/497 )
[9] => Array ( [ID] => 494 [name] => 2.4 Brand Beliefs [_more_] => /levels/1531866216/pages/494 )
[10] => Array ( [ID] => 491 [name] => 2.3 Brand Promise [_more_] => /levels/1531866216/pages/491 )
[11] => Array ( [ID] => 487 [name] => 2.2 Brand Story [_more_] => /levels/1531866216/pages/487 )
[12] => Array ( [ID] => 484 [name] => 2.1 Branding [_more_] => /levels/1531866216/pages/484 )
[13] => Array ( [ID] => 478 [name] => CHAPTER 2 CREATING THE BRAND HUB: FOUR KEY BRAND ELEMENTS [_more_] => /levels/1531866216/pages/478 )
[14] => Array ( [ID] => 473 [name] => LEVEL 1 ASSESSMENT [_more_] => /levels/1531866216/pages/473 )
[15] => Array ( [ID] => 464 [name] => 2.A-1 Brand Strategy Assignment [_more_] => /levels/1531866216/pages/464 )
[16] => Array ( [ID] => 461 [name] => 2.A-4 Student Instructions [_more_] => /levels/1531866216/pages/461 )
[17] => Array ( [ID] => 459 [name] => 2.A-3 Project Submission Form [_more_] => /levels/1531866216/pages/459 )
[18] => Array ( [ID] => 448 [name] => 1.A PRACTICUM ASSIGNMENTS [_more_] => /levels/1531866216/pages/448 )
[19] => Array ( [ID] => 445 [name] => 1.A-2 Topical Brainstorm Assignment [_more_] => /levels/1531866216/pages/445 )
[20] => Array ( [ID] => 432 [name] => 1.5 SUMMARY AND REVIEW [_more_] => /levels/1531866216/pages/432 )
[21] => Array ( [ID] => 427 [name] => 1.4 A New Inbound Model [_more_] => /levels/1531866216/pages/427 )
[22] => Array ( [ID] => 423 [name] => 1.3 The New Social Era of Marketing [_more_] => /levels/1531866216/pages/423 )
[23] => Array ( [ID] => 410 [name] => 1.2 Traditional Outbound Marketing vs. Digital Inbound Marketing [_more_] => /levels/1531866216/pages/410 )
[24] => Array ( [ID] => 394 [name] => 1.1 Consumer Acquisition from the Digital Landscape [_more_] => /levels/1531866216/pages/394 )
[25] => Array ( [ID] => 392 [name] => CHAPTER 1 INTRODUCING [_more_] => /levels/1531866216/pages/392 )
[26] => Array ( [ID] => 318 [name] => Project Submission Thank You [_more_] => /levels/1531866216/pages/318 ) ) )
```

Comment: Please read about [ask] questions here. You need to post what you have tried already. You say, "I have tried using a foreach and for loop." So, please post those attempts. Please also note that this kind of question has been asked many times before, so your question is likely to attract downvotes (for lack of research) and be marked as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through the array like so.

```
foreach($pages_array_name['0'] as $index => $sub_array) {
   echo "index is " . $index . "\n<br/>";
   echo "name is " . $sub_array['name'] . "\n<br/>";
   echo "_more_ is " . $sub_array['_more_'] . "\n<br/>";
   echo "\n<br/>"; // extra space
}
```